# Loop just fails to run

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flashdevelop

Using Flash Develop- the loops fails to run and programs just stops. 
Ordinary looking code other than the Japanese characters. 
The trace for i gives no results- other traces give an output.
The code before that loop gives images on Debug Flash Player.

```
package
{
    import adobe.utils.CustomActions;
        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    import Tile;
    import background;
    import tilecarrier;
    import Math;


    /**
     * ...
     * @author Michael
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var hand_current:Array = new Array();
    private var tiles:Array = new Array();
    private var pool:Array = new Array();
    private var baseset:Array=["あ・ア","え・え","い・イ","お・オ","う・ウ","か・カ","け・ヶ","き・キ","く・ク","こ・コ","さ・サ","し・シ","す・ス","そ・ソ","せ・セ","た・タ","て・テ","ち・チ","と・ト","つ・ツ","ら・ラ","れ・レ","り・リ","ろ・ロ","る・ル","だ・ダ","で・デ","ぢ・ヂ","ど／ド","づ・ヅ","ず・ズ","ざ・ザ","ぜ・ゼ","ぞ／ゾ","じ・ジ","な・ナ","に・二","の・ノ","ね・ネ","ぬ・ヌ","じゃ・ジャ","じゅ・ジュ","じょ・ジョ","を／ヲ","ん・ン","しゃ・シャ","しゅ・シュ","しょ・ショ","や・ヤ","ゆ・ユ","よ・ヨ","は・ハ","ひ・ヒ","ふ・フ","へ・ヘ","ほ・ホ","ば・バ","ぶ・ブ","び・ビ","ぼ・ボ","べ・ベ","ぱ・パ","ぴ／ピ","ぷ・プ","ぺ・ペ","ぽ・ポ","ま・マ","み・ミ","　む・ム","め・メ","も・モ","みゃ・ミャ","みゅ・ミャ","みょ・ミョ","きゃ・キャ","きゅ・キュ","きょ・キョ","にゃ・ニャ","にゅ・ニュ","にょ・ニョ","びゃ・びゃ","びゅ・ビュ","びょ・ビョ","ひゃ・ヒャ","ひゅ・ヒュ","ひょ・ヒョ","ぴゃ・ピャ","ぴゅ・ピュ","ぴょ・ピョ","っ・ッ"];
        private var startingset:Array=[3,1,2,2,6,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,4];
        private var altset:Array = ["あ・ア","え・え","い・イ","お・オ","う・ウ","か・カ","け・ヶ","き・キ","く・ク","こ・コ","さ・サ","し・シ","す・ス","そ・ソ","せ・セ","た・タ","て・テ","ち・チ","と・ト","つ・ツ","ら・ラ","れ・レ","り・リ","ろ・ロ","る・ル","だ・ダ","で・デ","ぢ・ヂ","ど／ド","づ・ヅ","ず・ズ","ざ・ザ","ぜ・ゼ","ぞ／ゾ","じ・ジ","な・ナ","に・二","の・ノ","ね・ネ","ぬ・ヌ","じゃ・ジャ","じゅ・ジュ","じょ・ジョ","お・オ","ん・ン","しゃ・シャ","しゅ・シュ","しょ・ショ","や・ヤ","ゆ・ユ","よ・ヨ","は・ハ","ひ・ヒ","ふ・フ","へ・ヘ","ほ・ホ","ば・バ","ぶ・ブ","び・ビ","ぼ・ボ","べ・ベ","ぱ・パ","ぴ／ピ","ぷ・プ","ぺ・ペ","ぽ・ポ","ま・マ","み・ミ","　む・ム","め・メ","も・モ","ま・マ","　む・ム","も・モ","か・カ","く・ク","こ・コ","な・ナ","ぬ・ヌ","の・ノ","ば・バ","ぶ・ブ","ぽ・ポ","は・ハ","ふ・フ","ほ・ホ","ぱ・パ","ぷ・プ","ぽ・ポ","っ・ッ"];
        private var basevalue:Array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 20, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1];
        private var altvalue:Array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 20, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1];

        public function Main():void

        {   if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);  }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {

            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
             var background1:Sprite = new background();
             background1.x = 0;
             background1.y = 0;
             addChild(background1);
              var tilebar:Sprite = new tilecarrier();
              tilebar.x = 0;
              tilebar.y = 480;
              addChild(tilebar);
             var returncarrier1:Sprite = new returncarrier();
              returncarrier1.x = 220;
              returncarrier1.y = 480;
              addChild(returncarrier1);


              createtile();
        }
private function createtile():void
                    {
                        trace("test");
                        var lengthbaseset:int;

            lengthbaseset = startingset.length;
            trace(lengthbaseset);
            var i:int;
            for (i = 0; i ==90; i=i+1)
            {
                trace(i);


            }
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhbq1vagrtyqmbs/Doesnot%20process%20loop.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For-loops run while the second argument is true. Here `i==90` is not true on the first attempt so the loop exits. You should change it to `i<90` if you want it to loop 90 times.

Comment: I was going to comment that it didn't help but I put the i as private and then it suddenly starting working and then as function var and worked again. FD is so buggy.